# Angular 6 + ASP .NET Core MVC inside Service Fabric

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to run a 'Stateless ASP.NET Core' API project with Angular 6 inside Service Fabric.

**What I do**

- Create ASP.NET Core API project.
- Create an Angular project within the ASP.NET Core project by running 'ng new ClientApp.
- Run ng build inside the Angular project to genereate the files.
- Edit Startup.cs (see code below)

  **Startup.cs**

  ```
  public class Startup
  {
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
          Configuration = configuration;
      }

      public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddMvc();

          // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
          services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
          {
              configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
          });
      }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
      {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          }
          else
          {
              app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
              app.UseHsts();
          }

          app.UseHttpsRedirection();
          app.UseStaticFiles();
          app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

          app.UseMvc(routes =>
          {
              routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
          });

          app.UseSpa(spa =>
          {
              // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
              // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

              spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

              if (env.IsDevelopment())
              {
                  spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

**Results**

!! If I create a normal (non-Service Fabric) ASP.NET Core API this approach works. !!

If I create the same inside Service Fabric I get the following Errors:

[image]

//EDIT

Solved it by following https://blog.bridging-it.de/blog/blogeintrag_4480.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by following the guide in this link https://blog.bridging-it.de/blog/blogeintrag_4480.html

It's in **German** but you should be able to figure it out with the help of Google Translate :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this NuGet package to your project:

`NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware`

And configure something like this:

`app.UseHsts(h=> h.MaxAge(days:100).preload())`